# Ionic 2 Google analytics integration

Tags: google-analytics, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I would like to use GA for my Ionic 2 app but for hybrid applications it looks a little bit tricky. 
In my `app.component` I have:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

      GoogleAnalytics.debugMode();
      GoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId(this.config.googleAnalyticsId).then(() => {
        console.log(this.TAG + ' ANALYTICS+');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(this.TAG + ' ANALYTICS- ' + err);
      });
      GoogleAnalytics.enableUncaughtExceptionReporting(true)
        .then((_success) => {
          console.log(_success);
        }).catch((_error) => {
        console.log(_error);
      });
...
```

And got such error log:

```
I: Google Analytics 10.2.98 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
     adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
     adb logcat -s GAv4
I: Logger is deprecated. To enable debug logging, please run:
   adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
W: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to UniversalAnalytics.debugMode blocked the main thread for 57ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
W: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: UniversalAnalytics549833873
   Result was: "Invalid action"
W: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: UniversalAnalytics549833875
   Result was: "Invalid action"
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "Tracker not started", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js (16)
```

The straightforward goal for me is to collect information about bugs during beta-testing. Because I didn't find enough information about this quite new subject for me, any hints or best practices would be appreciated.

Comment: hmm.. found [this project](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/GAProject) shared from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104609/error-implementing-google-analytics-into-ionic-2)..

Comment: Thank you for your involvement, I will check this.

Comment: no problem.. good luck